# how to give different frame or size to an images in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-camera

I am developing a document scanner app in android. I wants to know that how to change an image size or how to convert it to passport size photo or id card/CNIC. And how to scan passport in android studio.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the size of an image with the XML file easily:

```
android:layout_width="300sp"
android:layout_height="300sp"
```

You can also do it programmatically like so:

```
imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 30;
```

You can 'scan' passport by starting a camera intent like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE));
```

Comment: You can google the size of a passport photo or ID card.